# Auto Scroll Table Layout Panel does not start at top

Tags: c#, winforms

I am working on a very simple table layout application for getting started with learning C#. I am doing everything programmatic ally ( not through design editor)

I am trying to add scrolling onto the application. It seems to work fine, but it does not seem to start at the top of the horizontal range by default. I tried adding things like Max/min size, autoscroll margins etc., but nothing seems to have the desired effect. I am sure there is something simple I am missing.

Here is my current code as it relates to the problem.

```
        layout = new TableLayoutPanel();
        layout.Height = 1075;
        layout.Width = 704;
        layout.Name = "masterLayout";
        layout.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;


        layout.AutoScroll = true;

        int i = 0;
        foreach (Race r in ELECTION_DATA.races.OrderBy(o => o.race_id)) {
            layout.Controls.Add(new Label {  AutoSize = true, Text =r.race_id, Name=r.race_id, Width=300}, i, 0 );
            layout.Controls.Add(new TreeView {  AutoSize = true, Text = r.race_id, Name = r.race_id, Height = 1000, Width = 300 }, i,1);
            i += 1;
        }
        Controls.Add(layout);
```

Here is an image, The Label Control Is not visible because the scroll is offset to the beginning of the tree view.

[image]

How can I ensure the scroll always starts at the very top?

Comment: In Form.Load() => `this.VerticalScroll.Value = -1;`

Comment: That worked @Jimi thanks

Answer (score 0):

The ScrollLayoutPanel has a method called `ScrollControlIntoView` that will move a specific control inside the panel into view.  If you just scroll your first control into the view after you are done filling your panels, then that should ensure that the top is visible.  In other words:

```
// do your loop first...
foreach (...)
{
    layout.Controls.Add(...);
}

// then if any controls exist, scroll the first control into view 
if (layout.Controls.Count > 0)
{
    layout.ScrollControlIntoView(layout.Controls[0]);
}
```

Comment: seems to give same outcome

Comment: not seems, really works...